# Get multidimensional Array from doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I have an table like this:

| id //not index | origin |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | germany |
| 1 | usa |
| 2 | usa |
| 2 |  |

I want to get every Entity witch has an origin (!= '') but in a multidimensional Array, sorted by the id, looking like this:

```
[
 [
  {
   'id': '1',
   'origin': 'germany'
  },
  {
   'id': '1',
   'origin': 'usa'
  },
 ],
 [
  {
   'id': '2',
   'origin': 'usa'
  }
 ]
]
```

is this even possible with a query or do I have to do this in PHP?

Comment: You'd need a query to get the data out, and yes then some PHP to manipulate the data into the grouped structure you're proposing. Although personally I'd argue this is not a helpful structure for anyone receiving and trying to process that data. Why do you want it like that?

Comment: I need to dispatch RabbitMQ messages (Per id one message).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at all the answers I did it like so:

```
$allEntities = $this->repository->findWithOriginSortById();

$entitiesByid = [];
foreach ($allEntities as $entity) {
    $key = $entity->getId();
    $entitiesByid[$key][] = $entity;
}

/**
 * @return Entity[]
 */
public function findWithOriginSortById(): array
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('l');
    $qb
        ->where("l.origin != ''")
        ->orderBy('l.id')
    ;

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Comment: What's the diff with my solution ?

Comment: Nothing, but you edited your answer after I wrote mine. Or I didnt see ur changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **QueryBuilder** in your repository to do that.

```
public function getAll() {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('your_alias')
                ->select('your_alias.id, your_alias.origin');
    
            $qb
                ->where('your_alias.origin IS NOT NULL')
                ->orderBy('your_alias.id');
    
            return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

In your Controller :

```
$origins =  $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Origin::class)->getAll();

        $result = [];
        foreach ($origins as $element) {
            $result[$element[$element->getId()]][] = $element;
        }

       return $result;
```

Regards,

Comment: But this would just give me a onedimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the empty fields like this for e.x.

```
<pre><?php

// Source before
$before = array();
$before[] = array("1" => "germany");
$before[] = array("1" => "usa");
$before[] = array("2" => "usa");
$before[] = array("2" => "");


print_r($before);

// Source after
$after = array();
foreach ($before as $key => $value) {
    // Only add value, if aviable
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
        if (!empty($value2)) {
            $after[] = array($key2,$value2);
        }
    }
}
print_r($after);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => germany
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => usa
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [2] => usa
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [2] => 
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => germany
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => usa
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => usa
        )

)
```